# Truncating long text in list elements

Tags: html, css, overflow, truncate

I'm working on a responsive website with a breadcrumb navigation.

When the breadcrumb navigation is too long to be displayed in a single line it should be truncated with some elipses.

All solutions related to this I've found so far seem to rely on either having multi line text or just truncate text when it's too long for the containing element.

Basically my code looks like this:

```css
main {
  
  max-width: 600px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}

nav.breadcrumb {
  
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2em;
}

ul {
  
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  
  display: inline-block;
}

li + li {
  
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav class="breadcrumb">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Consectetur adipiscing elit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Praesent</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Duis ullamcorper faucibus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nunc lacus elit, luctus eu molestie id</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </nav>
</main>
```

Is there any CSS only solution to make this work?

Since there seems to be some confusion about what I am actually trying to achieve, here's an example:
[image]

Sorry if my question was missing some clarity.

Here's a pen for the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvwEZJ

Comment: I would use a javascript solution because the css solution in the posted answer (`text-overflow: ellipsis`) will cut off the end of your breadcrumb, which would be the most recent pages visited.  But maybe you can somehow align the right side of the breadcrumb to the right side of its container and cut off the beginning portion. That may look weird though. I have javascript code for a responsive breadcrumb that i can share with you :)

Answer (score 2):

Yep, there are some options to play around to achieve this effect, using `text-overflow` property.

Here are some examples on how I used it, maybe it would come in handy for you:

**1. Flexbox**

- set the `<ul>` tag to `display: flex`
- children `<li>` to flex: 1 100%, so theyll stretch evenly across the ul, also needed overflow hidden and text-overflow: ellipsis;
- done.

**2. Table trick**

- set the `<ul>` to `display: table`
- Children `<li>` to display: table-cell & use a max width here so theyll stop somewhere and the '...' will appear; also needed overflow hidden and text-overflow: ellipsis;
- done.

**3. Fixed width + float, display inline block/block ...**

- set the `<li>` to float, or display inline block, and use a fixed width on em, so theyll stop at some point, and not go onto the next line; also needed overflow hidden and text-overflow: ellipsis;
- done.

Check out the **[demos here](http://jsfiddle.net/r31ykLxz/2/)**, or snippet bellow, and hope this helps you

```css
/*new stuff*/

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*flex*/

.flex {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}
.flex > li {
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
/*table way*/

.table {
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
}
.table > li {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-cell;
  max-width: 40px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
/*the fixed way*/

.fixed {
  padding: 0;
}
.fixed li {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 14%;
  /*7items divided by 100*/
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
main {
  max-width: 600px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
nav.breadcrumb {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2em;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li + li {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>The flex way</h1>
<main>
  <nav class="breadcrumb">
    <ul class='flex'>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Consectetur adipiscing elit</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Praesent</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Duis ullamcorper faucibus</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Nunc lacus elit, luctus eu molestie id</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>

<h1>The table way</h1>
<main>
  <nav class="breadcrumb">
    <ul class='table'>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Consectetur adipiscing elit</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Praesent</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Duis ullamcorper faucibus</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Nunc lacus elit, luctus eu molestie id</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>

<h1>The fixed way</h1>
<main>
  <nav class="breadcrumb">
    <ul class='fixed'>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Consectetur adipiscing elit</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Praesent</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Duis ullamcorper faucibus</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Nunc lacus elit, luctus eu molestie id</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
```

Comment: @MichaelHumelsine thanks! I was about to drop it when I saw the comment on your answer, and I wasnt too sure about it, but I was almost done with it, so might aswell release it :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `text-overflow:ellipsis;`  Check you this link:

http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html

Comment: That wont work since it only truncates when the text is too long for it's containing element. 

I need some solution for when multiple elements are combined too long for a single line.

Comment: @FelixWienberg so elements should stay on the same line, and add the '...' at the end when words are too long? or what would be the expected result?

Comment: Can you clarify your question then because that's what you asked for:
When the breadcrumb navigation is too long to be displayed in a single line it should be truncated with some elipses.

Comment: @MichaelHumelsine yes, that's right, but since the text of the seperate links are not too long to fit in a single line, text-overflow wont work.

It's the combined length of the links that is too long to fit a single row.

Comment: Yes...?  You set the text-overflow property on your ul.  What am I missing?  See Crispy-George's answer since he was kind enough to provide a fiddle.